# Magnific popup: getting “The image could not be loaded”

Tags: magnific-popup

I can't make a gallery work with magnific popup. When I click on a picture I receive “The image could not be loaded”.

Here is the html file listing images:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='picture'><img src='images/gallery/a.jpg'/></div>
    <div class='picture'><img src='images/gallery/b.jpg'/></div>
    <div class='picture'><img src='images/gallery/c.jpg'/></div>
    <div class='picture'><img src='images/gallery/d.jpg'/></div>
    <div class='picture'><img src='images/gallery/e.jpg'/></div>
</div>
```

Here the jquery code:

```
$.get( 'html/gallery.html', function( data ) {
        $('#page_content').append(data);

        $('.container').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: 'div',
        gallery:{
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>',
            tPrev: 'Previous (Left arrow key)',
            tNext: 'Next (Right arrow key)',
            tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter">%curr% of %total%</span>'
        }
    });
```

I tried to change the "delegate" value to 'div' or 'img' but no result. (I followed this [Magnific popup: getting "The image could not be loaded" and image url is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412335/magnific-popup-getting-the-image-could-not-be-loaded-and-image-url-is-undefin))

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well problem solved...
Magnific popup needs a href attribute in order to work.

Solution :

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='picture' href='images/gallery/a.jpg'><img src='images/gallery/a.jpg'/></div>
    <div class='picture' href='images/gallery/b.jpg'><img src='images/gallery/b.jpg'/></div>
    ....
</div>
```